# What does 企業 mean: property of the person or business company?

Tags: word-choice, traditional-characters

Is (in traditional chinese) "企業" - noun or adjective? Is this menaing closer to "readiness and willingness to take initiative" or to "a company"?

Comment: It may not mean the same thing in every classical occurrence.  If you have a specific occurrence in mind you should give some context.

Comment: 企業 is an **enterprise**.

Comment: Ah, do you mean in modern Chinese using traditional characters?  In that case Google search entirely supports Stan's answer.

Comment: @Colin McLarty, the context is next. There is one psycholinguistic study of values (such as "Friendship", "Happiness", "Love"). And one of the values is "企業" (yes, that is in modern Chinese using traditional characters). By "企業" authors mean value: property of a person's character, such as "active, energetic, practical, businesslike". Is "企業" suitable for this? Or it is mean just enterprise like IBM or other corporation (not property of a person's character!)?

Comment: Use 企业精神 if you want to describe a person having an enterprising character.

Comment: @Question Overflow, is "企业精神" written in traditional characters? And do I understand correctly, that "企業" mean something like "facility, organization"?

Comment: If the authors are not Chinese native speaker, I guess I understand how it comes like this now. They just want a word expressing **enterprise** (the ability to think of new and effective things to do, together with an eagerness to do them) in Chinese, and after looking a dictionary they decide to translate it into 企業. However it's not proper, @QuestionOverflow 's `企業精神` is a good one ... but too general ... formal translations would be `開拓精神/進取精神/事業心 etc.`

Comment: @drobnbobn  Can you give a cite to the psycholinguistic study?

Comment: @Colin McLarty, I have only paper version in Russian language, but I would try to find suitable link.

Comment: Even the scanned version of that paper version is nice, please upload.

Comment: If you want to describe a quality of person in general, you should avoid 企业精神. It doesn't mean the spirit _like_ running a business, instead, it means the spirit _for_ running a business. This word is best suitable for person who is actually running a (start-up) company.

Answer (score 1):

企 refers to an attempt or expectation, and 業 means "industry." So 企業 would best translate into "enterprise." That would refer to an "early stage" company that is trying to make a name for itself but is not fully established.

Answer (score 1):

"企業"is a fixed phrase that cannot be seperated from each character, its whole meaning:
company,enterprise.